# GCP API Gateway: Do unauthenticated calls count towards usage for billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have setup a simple API on API Gateway and restricted access to it via API Keys. Now, if a user calls the API with a missing/invalid key, would that count towards billing (https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/pricing)?

In the console dashboards, I can see unauthenticated requests showing up in 4xx errors and overall request count, so it looks like they are being counted towards billing. If so, how can I protect my API against attacks where a malicious user bombards unauthenticated requests to increase my bill?

On the other hand, if they are not counted, how can I view my current billed usage (like which pricing tier: 0-2M, 2M-1B, 1B+ I am in). In Billing reports, it just shows the cost which is 0 right now.

Comment: Yes. Any request to API gateway count.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. What would be the solution to DOS attacks? Does GCP have some basic security to prevent simple attacks like 
`while true; do
  curl myApiEndpoint?key=randomKey
done`
so I don't need to worry about it? I also came across Cloud Armor but that's 3000$ per month

Comment: Hmmm, you can do things but API Gateway is not mature enough to offer a full protection. let me explain. You can set up a Load Balancer in front of your API Gateway: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg Then, activate Cloud Armor and you have a WAF that protect you against DDoS attacks!! https://cloud.google.com/armor?hl=en BUT, the API Gateway public URL is still active. Not easy to guess but not perfectly safe either

Comment: For a project that's just starting out, Cloud Armor is too expensive. I guess for now, I'll try to hide my url the best I can.

Comment: Security is mainly risk management. You can accept the risk and do nothing. You can also  take action to mitigate it (but will incur costs).